3 panels in VS Code like RStudio
I am trying to run R scripts on VS Code, but I cannot manage to set the layout in my preferred way.
Specifically, I would like to recreate something similar to the 4-panel structure of RStudio (with the addition of all the VS Code side-bars on the left side).
However, when I move the terminal or the plot panel on the right of the editor, I cannot add a second panel to the right-below. It seems like I can only add it centrally, below the editor.
Am I missing something? Is this just a feature missing from VS Code?
EDIT 1: I would like to have code on the left, console on the top-right, and plots on the bottom-right.

what does the arrangement you want look like? what's in the top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right? please [edit] this info into your question

@starball done!

that's only three panels?

That is correct, because the 4th panel of RStudio, which would be the one showing the elements stored in the environment, I already on the left side bar. I will edit the Q
